# How to combine internet connections from multiple devices in a single device?

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, router

My main machine: 2015 Macbook Pro. It has a maximum download speed of 8MB/s using wifi which I don't have control over. This machine has the ability to reach +60MB/s however it doesn't because of the router limitations (I assume). So **our objective is to increase the download speed as much as possible using my other devices below.**

I'm speed testing all devices at the same time using the same wifi.

iPhone 7: 12MB/s

Android: 5MB/s

Windows Laptop: 8MB/s

I did some research and I think it is possible to combine them. However I'm really lost on how to actually do this. How can we combine internet connections from multiple devices in a single device?

Comment: You’d need to use a commercial service like Speedify to do this. It’s a complicated issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dispatch-proxy](https://github.com/alexkirsz/dispatch-proxy). It is open-source and available for Mac.
Installation guide [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpHJo.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can do anything you want with a communications pipe, or set of pipes, if both ends are in agreement on where and how to use those pipes.

The "agreement" for anything Internet connected is generally the TCP/IP protocol suite, which includes the long-established and standardized protocols TCP, IP, UDP, ICMP.  Anything that's Internet accessible can be counted on to speak one of these.

And these protocols are heavily based on the notion of "two and only two nodes on either end of a pipe, and each end has a unique and single IP."

Can you change the agreement to something that works differently?  Sure - for devices you own (and can change the software configuration of) on both ends of any set of pipes.

If you are talking about standard Internet access in the way most people understand it - you own and can configure your own computer, but you can't change the configuration of Google, Facebook, Amazon, or any other computer.  Hence you are stuck on the standard model above.

If you had a server in the cloud somewhere, you could set up something like SCTP where you combine bandwidth in the manner you describe, between the devices in your home and that single server only.  But you can't change the protocols supported by a system if you don't own it and can't change the configuration of it.